# Predefined contrasts with lme4

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, contrasts

in my current project I'm interested in setting certain contrasts ahead of analysis. I have five experimental groups, the control one (A), two groups with low dose (B and C) of chemical and two with high dose of chemical (D and E). For data analysis I would like to fit a quite simple mixed-effect model with R's lme4 package:

```
model <- lmer(responseVar ~ treatment + (1 | replicate))
```

at the end I'm interested in two types of comparisons.

- any experimental group vs. control (B vs A, C vs A and so on). This could be done by using treatment contrast and is not a problem
- two specific between groups comparison, namely B vs. D and C vs. E.

Can anybody help me with setting custom contrasts for data analysis?

Comment: Did you try the `glht` function from the `multcomp` package? ([Examples of use](https://stat.ethz.ch/~meier/teaching/anova/contrasts-and-multiple-testing.html).)

Comment: Thank you, @chl!